# Alembic few modules to single database, with specific file migrations

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic, sqlalchemy-migrate

We need to build a large application that split to multiple modules. Each module has own alembic version table, and in each module we generated the alembic migration, but the problem when I generate a migration file, inside it generate drop of all database tables, I can't specify the context of each migration.

What I want to do  is in each module, I want to generate only the migration script about models inside this module and not for others ?

I don't know if I must use a schema per module to resolve that ?

Comment: You could have a small service to handle migrations. This service should be in charge of: a) delivering a new id to any modules that requires a migration; b) performing migrations gathering all files from each module. Then, there's only one alembic version table with all your changes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what I want is to generate file migrations by schema and not one migrations file for all modules